# Query using Order By in JDBC request

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter

I have a jdbc request in jmeter where i am searching user data from the table.But data shows multiple records so i need to use order by latest updated date.
[image]

SQL is working fine but display multiple record,how can i use

```
 SELECT CREATION_DATE,PROCESS_FLAG FROM 
 CUST  where ORDER_NUMBER =? order by 
 LAST_UPDATE_DATE desc;
```

because it is giving me error `invalid character` while trying using jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't allow to use `;` sign at the end of [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) select statement.

> Do not enter a trailing semi-colon.

Just remove last character and SQL will be executed wìthout error.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess what's wrong without seeing request and response details and knowing what database and which JDBC driver you're using.

Try the next tips:

1. Check your `${OrderID}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
2. Check generated query and parameter substitution using "Request" tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
3. Check that you are using appropriate [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database (not too old, not too new)
4. Check if you can run the same query using [plain Java code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)